# How can I automatically add svn auto-props at the beginning of my files if they just exist in the log of svn?

Tags: svn

The task is to add automatically svn-keywords on the beginning of code files e.g. *.java, *.c, *.cpp and so on.

I already know that I can add for example $URL$ at the beginning of my file and svn automatically types in the keyword.

How can I add the keywords without typing anything in the file before.
Thought about a batch-file or something.

Please help me.

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you figure out how to open and edit a file from a batch? Did you try to set the required SVN property?

Comment: So far I set the required SVN property, Inserted the comments $URL$, no I didn't find out how to open and edit a svn file from a batch when updating the branch...looking forward for help :O

Comment: Not sure if I get it right... You are able to set the SVN property, right? You are able to insert the text into the file, right? Then where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `sed` maybe this can help:

```
find YOUR_SOURCE_DIRECTORY -name \*.java -or -name \*.cpp -or -name \*.c -exec sed -i'' $'1i\\\n$URL$\n' {} +
```

Comment: this solution will be just helping when executing the command. I need a solution which automatically inserts the props in the head of the file everytime I commit the files to the repository.

Comment: Everytime when you *commit*? Do you want many `$URL$` in every file? I don't understand your problem.